# How do you mock a singleton dependency in JMockit?

Tags: jmockit, java-11

I'm working on some automated unit and integration tests for a robot. As you could imagine, a robot has a lot of sensor objects and such that would need mocking during testing.

One of the dependencies is a singleton designed not to be instantiated by anything but itself. As I understood it (I'm new to JMockit), once a class is annotated with `@Mocked` all of its methods and constructors are mocked. [JMockit Documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#mocked):

> There are three different mocking annotations we can use when declaring mock fields and parameters: @Mocked, which will mock all methods and constructors on all existing and future instances of a mocked class

However I'm noticing (via the usage of a breakpoint) that the real class' constructor is being called and failing to access a sensor, causing the tests to fail.

Here is the relevant part of the singleton I'm trying to mock. Note that I **cannot** modify this class:

```java
public class DriverStation() {
    // This line in particular is an issue.
    private static DriverStation currentInstance = new DriverStation();

    public static DriverStation getInstance() {
        return DriverStation.instance;
    }

    private DriverStation() {
        // This constructor cannot be called during tests.
    }
}
```

And here is my test code:

```java
public class BlingControllerTest {
    @Mocked
    private DriverStation station;

    @Tested
    private BlingController blingController;

    /**
     * Tests getting the robot's operation period while not in a real match.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetOperationPeriodDuringRealMatch(@Mocked DriverStation station) {
        new Expectations(DriverStation.class) {{
            DriverStation.getInstance();
            result = station;

            station.isFMSAttached();
            result = true;

            station.isAutonomous();
            returns(true, false);
        }};
    }
}
```

[Full source also available on GitHub](https://github.com/FRC2706/2019-2706-Robot-Code/tree/bling-tests/src/test/java/ca/team2706/frc/robot/commands/bling)

I should also mention that for some reason calling the singleton's constructor locally during tests isn't a problem, but when the tests are run on travis-ci it is a problem.

Stacktrace from running on travis-ci:

```
ca.team2706.frc.robot.commands.bling.BlingControllerTest > testGetOperationPeriodDuringRealMatch STANDARD_ERROR
    java.io.IOException: wpiHaljni could not be loaded from path or an embedded resource.
        attempted to load for platform /linux/x86-64/
        at edu.wpi.first.wpiutil.RuntimeLoader.loadLibrary(RuntimeLoader.java:79)
        at edu.wpi.first.hal.JNIWrapper.<clinit>(JNIWrapper.java:25)
        at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.DriverStation.<init>(DriverStation.java:194)
        at edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.DriverStation.<clinit>(DriverStation.java:132)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.ensureThatClassIsInitialized(TestRun.java:138)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineType(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:65)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.TypeRedefinition.redefineType(TypeRedefinition.java:28)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldType(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:78)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldType(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:65)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldTypes(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:53)
        at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.<init>(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:33)
        at mockit.integration.TestRunnerDecorator.handleMockFieldsForWholeTestClass(TestRunnerDecorator.java:142)
        at mockit.integration.TestRunnerDecorator.updateTestClassState(TestRunnerDecorator.java:40)
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Dependency Injection.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Find a DI framework or library like Spring or Guice and delegate instance management to that, instead of keeping the instance in a static variable in the Class.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku I would rather do that but the DriverStation class as I mentioned in the original question is uneditable. It's a library provided to us that we have to use.

Comment: Make a wrapper class around the instance, then.

Comment: You probably just need to stub out the static initialization of the singleton class (there is an attribute in `@Mocked` for that). Also: a) your test is mocking `DriverStation` *three* times - you only need one; and b) there is no need to record an expectation on `DriverStation.getInstance()`.

Comment: @Rogério good feedback, in the haze of debugging I didn't realize that I'd mocked DriverStation three times. Also thanks for pointing to the attribute to mock out the static initializer, that worked.